# setValue() doesn't work when TreeList is bound to a DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, treelist

I iterate through treelist to look for a specific treelist Node. This `treeList1` is bound to a datasource from designer.

```
for (int i =0; i<treeList1.Nodes.Count; i++)
    {
     if (GL_ID == treeList1.Nodes[i].GetValue(0).ToString()) {
     //treeList2 is unbound and it works
     treeList2.Nodes[0].SetValue(treeListColumn1, "myval");
     treeList1.Nodes[i].SetValue(colGL_Name_VC, GL_Name_VC);
     treeList1.Nodes[i].SetValue(colBS_Category_VC, BS_Category_VC);
     treeList1.Nodes[i].SetValue(colStatus_BT, STATUS_BT);
break;
            }
```

After setting the value when I do `getValue()` there's no change.

Answer (score 0):

If TreeList is correctly configured, this approach should work regardless of whether you use the control in bound or unbound mode. Also, if your task is to find a node and update its values, I suggest you use the [TreeList](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList).[FindNodeByFieldValue](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList.FindNodeByFieldValue(System.String-System.Object)) method instead of iterating through nodes manually. I illustrated the main idea of this approach below:

```
        var targetNode = treeList1.FindNodeByFieldValue(targetColumn.FieldName, GL_ID);
        targetNode.SetValue(colGL_Name_VC, GL_Name_VC);
        targetNode.SetValue(colBS_Category_VC, BS_Category_VC);
        targetNode.SetValue(colStatus_BT, STATUS_BT);
```